# Таблица с фиксированым хедером и первым столбцом

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

Подскажите есть [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

квартира это одна таблица и дата это тоже отдельная таблица.всего на скриншоте 6 таблиц.

Подскажите, как сделать фиксированный хедер и первыл столбец с квартирами?

Comment: https://datatables.net/ умеет. Или вам для собственного развития велосипед нужен?

Answer (score 0):

Задать им свойство position: fixed, если я правильно понял вопрос.